# Wrong Backprop updates in Batchnorm

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation, batch-normalization

I have these updates for Backprop, please let me know where the dx part is wrong. In the computation graph, I am using X, sample_mean and sample_var. Thanks for your help

```
(x, norm, sample_mean, sample_var, gamma, eps) = cache
dbeta = np.sum(dout, axis = 0)
dgamma = np.sum(dout * norm, axis = 0)
dxminus = dout * gamma / np.sqrt(sample_var + eps)
dmean = - np.sum(dxminus, axis = 0)
dxmean = np.full(x.shape, 1.0/x.shape[0]) * dmean
dvar = np.sum(dout * gamma * (x - sample_mean), axis = 0)
dxvar = dvar * (-1 / x.shape[0]) * np.power(x, -1.5) * (x - sample_mean)
dx = dxminus + dxmean + dxvar
```

[BatchNorm Computational Graph I used for deriving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fISq.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Your `dx` formula doesn't look right, because `x` node is going to receive the backward message from two other nodes (one is the sum and the other is the mean), and looks like you're computing just one component:

[image: backprop]

So it should look something like this:

```
dx1 = dxmu1 + dxmu2
dmu = -1 * np.sum(dxmu1+dxmu2, axis=0)
dx2 = 1. /N * np.ones((N,D)) * dmu
dx = dx1 + dx2
```

The picture is from [this wonderful post](https://kratzert.github.io/2016/02/12/understanding-the-gradient-flow-through-the-batch-normalization-layer.html). You can find the complete code there too.

Comment: I have updated and added computational graph. Please let me know where is the mistake. Thanks for the above answer and help.